# Keydown event not using newest input value

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a webapplication with a textfield to search in a dropdownlist. 
I use this textbox for the search

```
@Html.TextBox("Search",
              "", 
              new { id = "Search" + @Model.ID + "",
                    @class = "Search" })
```

in this dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
         m => m.MainSynonymId, 
         new SelectList(ViewBag.SynonymList, 
                        "ID",
                        "Name",
                         Model.MainSynonymId), 
         new { id = "MainSynonymList" + @Model.ID + "", 
               @class = "SynonymList TableClass" })
```

If i fill in something in the search input, the dropdown should automatically only contents elements, that contains the searched letters. So i implemented a jquery method on keydown to trigger all inputs, send them to server and send back with json to the client.
Here is the jQuery:

```
$('.Search').bind("keydown", function (event) {
            var fieldId = $(this).attr('id');
            var field = "Search";
            var id = fieldId.replace(field, '');
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetSpecific", "Models")', { Name: $('#' + fieldId + '').val() }, function (data) {
                var items;
                $.each(data, function (i, g) {
                    items += "<option value='" + g.Value + "'>" + g.Text + "</option>";
                    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                });
                $('#MainSynonymList' + id + '').html(items);
            });
                });
```

The communication work almost fine. The only problem is, that the method on keydown not take the used key but all other in the input field.

For example: I wrote in the input field "example", after i press the last "e" the triggered event oly send the word "exampl" to the server. 
What have i do wrong?

Comment: Why not use `$(this).val()` instead of using such a convoluted code?

Comment: Good idea but it only replace one point in the code. I still need to get the id from the textfield because it is in a table with such a method in each row and every method should only trigger the dropdown in it´s row.

Comment: Only the textbox on which this event is triggered will be referred by `$(this)`.

Comment: Yes i replaced `$('#' + fieldId + '').val()` with `$(this).val()` but i still need `var fieldId = $(this).attr('id');var field = "Search"; var id = fieldId.replace(field, '');`to choose the right dropdown `$('#MainSynonymList' + id + '').html(items);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `keydown` event is firing before the value is added to the field. Use `keyup` or `keypress` instead.

Comment: Thank you thats what i missed :)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the keydown to keyup in your code.

this should become

```
$('.Search').bind("keydown", function (event) {}
```

this

```
$('.Search').bind("keyup", function (event) {}
```

here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/HEjAn/)